# Can't copy file due to special characters in filename

Tags: php, symfony, filesystems

I would like to copy a file in Symfony2, but I'm getting an error:

`Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\FileNotFoundException: Failed to copy "../../../public_html/uploads/images/2011/03/MG_3839-ba�o.jpg" because file does not exist`

```
$fs = new Filesystem();
$fs->copy('../../../public_html/uploads/images/'.$image, '../../../public_html/uploads/tmp/'.$image, true);
```

`var_dump($image)` gives `2011/03/MG_3839-baño.jpg` and `mb_detect_encoding($image)` gives `ASCII`. Why is Symfony looking for a filename containing the � sign? I can't figure out where that sign is coming from, since `var_dump()` gives the correct filename.

Comment: probably the charset is not correct so the file is not found. When creating it, it does not matter as it probably is being created with the character badly encoded

Comment: The above comment can serve as an approach to fix this issue for you: check what file gets created by you attempt. Check the name. Then try changing the encoding of your `$image` variables content until the file name is generated with the name you expect. That should be the right encoding then, as a rough guess.

Comment: In general today one should implement web pages and http servers to use utf-8 encoding. All modern unixoid systems work flawless with that, only MS-Windows still has a few issues with that. The character you expect is a southern european character (spanish). You will always have problems using that in an iso-8859 encoding (latin-something) inside php, since php simply does not support that correctly. Go for unicode, so utf-8.

Comment: It clearly an encoding problem, that's what I knew already. However, it's unclear to me why ``File($image)`` is working, but ``$fs->copy($image, $newfile)`` isn't.

Comment: @arkascha What do I have to change to unicode? Symfony2 is using UTF-8 by default and my database (MySQL/PDO) it set to UTF-8 as well.

Comment: You question about whether the file creatin works has been answered by gontrollez above. The file is created, why shouldn't it? It just won't be created with the name you expect. You _did_ check the files ystem for that created file, didn't you?

Comment: About the encoding: first check the encoding used inside the variable `$image`. Best for this always is to use a hexeditor, that is the only way to really see the encoding of some string. Every other alternative hides the internal encoding behind some more or less intelligent code to "interpret the encoding correctly", which obviously cannot really work. So you will have to somehow raw dump that strings content. Also, do _not_ rely on phps autodetection of encoding. They are proven to not being reliable. Which is not phps fault, since that problem simply is not solvable automatically.

Comment: @gontrollez @arkascha ``new File($image)`` doesn't create a file, so I can't check what's the exact filename. It only makes a File() object, or am I wrong?

Comment: @gontrollez @arkascha Sorry, I'm still stuck. var_dump($filename) gives "baño", but ``Filesystem()`` gives an error because "ba�o" doesn't exist. I can't find out were (and why) my string (ñ) turns to the � sign.

Comment: I just found out that ``new File($image)`` isn't working either, but simply doesn't throw an error. But that doesn't solve the problem. I can't figure out what's happening.

Comment: The php file where you type "baño" will be encoded ISO-8859 or UTF8. Try converting the file to the other charset.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command :

```
$fs = new Filesystem();
```

> **$image = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $image);**

```
$fs->copy('../../../public_html/uploads/images/'.$image, '../../../public_html/uploads/tmp/'.$image, true);
```

Answer (score -1):

$file_name = strtr($file_name, "áéíóúâêôàãõçÁÉÍÓÚÂÊÔÀÃÕÇºª", "aeiouaeoaaocAEIOUAEOAAOCoa");

Comment: That means it will look for 'bano.jpg', while the filename is 'baño.jpg'.